# Bedeutung von "wahrnehmungsbereit"

Tags: meaning

Das Wort "wahrnehmungsbereit" scheint ja überall auf Unverständnis zu stoßen. Mal abgesehen davon, dass es weder von Duden, noch von einem anderen Wörterbuch anerkannt wird, fällt es mir schwer, die Bedeutung des Wortes zu erschließen.

> **Fahrer muss wahrnehmungsbereit sein**
>   Ferner wird geregelt, dass im Rahmen der bestimmungsgemäßen Verwendung die automatisierte Fahrfunktion zur Fahrzeugsteuerung verwendet werden kann, "wenn der Fahrzeugführer besonders geregelte Pflichten zur unverzüglichen Wiederaufnahme der Fahrzeugsteuerung beachtet". Einem Änderungsantrag der Koalitionsfraktionen folgend hat der Verkehrsausschuss klargestellt, dass der Fahrzeugführer sich im Falle, dass die hoch- und vollautomatisierte Fahrfunktion die Kontrolle über das Auto übernommen hat, „vom Verkehrsgeschehen und der Fahrzeugführung abwenden“ darf. Er müsse aber so wahrnehmungsbereit sein, dass er die Steuerung wieder übernehmen kann, wenn er vom System dazu aufgefordert wird.

Lediglich der Deutsche Bundestag erläutert, was es damit auf sich hat. Aus diesem trockenen Papierdeutsch wird mir allerdings die Bedeutung des Wortes nicht klar, deswegen bitte ich um eine, soweit es möglich ist, verständliche Definition des Begriffes "wahrnehmungsbereit".

Comment: Die Antwort findet sich im letzten Satz: Der Fahrer muss in der Lage sein, die Steuerung wieder zu übernehmen, wenn er vom System dazu aufgefordert wird. Was ist daran unverständlich?

Comment: Wahrnehmungsbereit sein heißt bereit sein, etwas wahrzunehmen.

Comment: @Rha Hier ist also von selbstfahrenden Autos die Rede? Wie bereits erwähnt, verstehe ich keinen der 3 langen Sätze

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Und bezieht sich das Wort auschließlich auf den obigen Bereich oder findet es auch anderswo Verwendung?

Comment: Dass nur ein Bruchteil der möglichen Wörter im Deutschen in einem Wörterbuch stehen sollte dir doch nicht neu sein.

Comment: @Dreikäsehoch Die Frage war doch "Was heißt wahrnehmungsbereit?" und nicht "Ich verstehe diesen Text nicht, weil er zu lange Sätze enthält, könnt ihr ihn mir erklären?"

Comment: @Janka Stimmt, allerdings gehe ich davon aus, dass Wörtern, die in keinem Wörterbuch stehen, eher selten verwendet werden und daher ungewöhnlich rüberkommen.

Comment: @RHa Der Text interessiert mich nicht, ich wollte dadurch zeigen, dass es für mich nicht offensichtlich ist, wovon der Textabschnitt handelt. Ihre Erklärung genügt mir allerdings vollkommen.

Comment: Selten vorkommen werden sie sicher, umso klarer muss also die Bedeutung sein. Und *wahrnehmungsbereit* ist genauso gebildet wie *fahrbereit*, *startbereit*, *bremsbereit* usw.

Comment: Das Verb „wahrnehmen“ hat mehrere Bedeutungen, nämlich (ich spicke dafür im Duden): mit den Sinnen aufnehmen, (eine Gelegenheit) nutzen, sich um etwas kümmern. Der Wortbestandteil „-bereit“ kann gerüstet oder willens heißen. Die genaue Bedeutung von „wahrnehmungsbereit“ ergibt sich also nicht problemlos.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, zweifellos richtig und hat das eine Problem auf zwei andere reduziert ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es ist nicht verwunderlich, dass das Wort *wahrnehmungsbereit* weder im Duden noch in einem anderen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache geführt wird. Denn es handelt sich um ein zusammengesetztes und bis vor kurzem ziemlich ungebräuchliches Wort.

Die deutsche Sprache ist dafür bekannt, durch Aneinanderreihen von Wörtern (ggf. mit einem s-Einschub zwischen ihnen) neue Wörter ad hoc zu erschaffen: die meisten dieser Composita finden keinen Eingang in die Lexika, denn sie kommen und gehen; ihre Bedeutung wird vom Leser/Hörer aus der Zusammensetzung abgeleitet, er muss dafür das zusammengesetzte Wort nicht schon davor kennengelernt haben.

Manche Zusammensetzungsbausteine sind besonders beliebt und erhalten daher eigene Lexika-Einträge, wie zum Beispiel [*-bereit*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_bereit). Diesem Duden-Eintrag kann man einige gängige "Bereitschaftsbeispiele" entnehmen: *funktionsbereit*, *sprungbereit*, *abrufbereit*, *startbereit*, ...

Man kann weitere eigene konstruieren: *reaktionsbereit*, *abkopplungsbereit*, *ablesebereit*... Auch ihre Bedeutung ist direkt aus der Zusammensetzung erschließbar. Und so leitet sich auch die Bedeutung von *wahrnehmungsbereit* aus seinen Bausteinen ab: *bereit zur Wahrnehmung*.

Was das im Einzelnen konkret bedeuten soll, ist natürlich - wie sollte es anders sein? - auch kontextabhängig. Der deutsche Philosoph Edmund Husserl, der den Begriff *wahrnehmungsbereit* vor etwa 100 Jahren in seinen Werken verwendet hat, wird eine etwas andere Bedeutung im Sinn gehabt haben als der Verkehrsausschuss des Deutschen Bundestages.

Im vorliegenden Beispielsatz

> Er müsse aber so wahrnehmungsbereit sein, dass er die Steuerung wieder übernehmen kann, wenn er vom System dazu aufgefordert wird.

bedeutet *wahrnehmungsbereit*, dass der Fahrzeugführer (=die vom selbst fahrenden Auto gefahrene Hauptperson) das Signal, durch welches das Auto ihn zur Übernahme der Steuerung auffordert, nicht übersehen/überhören sollte. Legt sich der Fahrzeugführer dagegen tief schlafen oder schirmt er seine Augen und Ohren so ab, dass er das Signal nicht mehr mitbekommt (**=nicht mehr wahrnimmt**), weil er sich zum Beispiel einen Film anschaut und ganz und gar darin vertieft ist, dann haftet er, falls das selbst fahrende Auto nach dem Signal einen Unfall baut; sprich: der Fahrzeugführer und nicht etwa der Hersteller des selbst fahrenden Autos muss dann für den Schaden aufkommen.

Comment: Ich denke, meine Antwort ist weitgehend deckungsgleich mit deiner Argumentation. Ich glaube aber nicht, dass die *Wahrnehmung des Signals* wirklich für den Übergang der Haftung ausreicht, sondern dass das Reagieren (zweite Bedeutung) den Ausschlag gibt.

Comment: @guidot Die *Wahrnehmung des Signals* allein reicht für den Übergang der Haftung in der Tat nicht aus (*ausreichend* vs. *notwendig*). Das Wort und seine Auslegung ist das Ergebnis des politischen Hick-Hacks zwischen den "Fortschrittlichen" (F.) und den PKW-Herstellern (Lobby). Forderung der F.: komplette Freistellung der Insassen von der Haftung; Gegenarbeit der Lobby: möglichst viel Haftung auf den "Fahrzeugführer" abwälzen; Ministeriumsentwurf: "muss jederzeit wahrnehmungsbereit sein"; Aufschrei der F.; Zurückrudern des Ministeriums: "so dass er die Steuerung wieder übernehmen kann".

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort *wahrnehmen* hat zwei deutlich unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

1. empfinden als Überbegriff zu *sehen*, *hören*, *fühlen*, ...
2. eine Tätigkeit oder Funktion ausüben

Mit der Bedeutung 1 ist die Zusammensetzung weitgehend sinnlos, denn empfinden kann man immer, es sei denn, man wäre bewusstlos, betäubt oder massiv abgelenkt. Für diesen Sachverhalt gibt es bereits ein deutlich treffenderes Wort, nämlich *aufmerksam*.

Meiner Meinung nach ist Bedeutung 2 gemeint, jederzeit bereit sein, das Steuer zu übernehmen, also die Fahrerrolle wieder wahrzunehmen.